# Using Lyx on Windows 10, missing packages and modules

Tags: lyx, miktex, document-classes, missing

As mentioned in the title, I installed Lyx on my windows 10 machine. It already had a Miktex bundle installation on it.

Whenever I open the user guide, I'm told some files are missing so output/compilation is not possible. The files missing are:

1. Koma-script scrbook.cls
2. fancyhdr.sty
3. enumitem.hdr

I used my miktex package manager (admin) to install all the files, included the tex/latex folder in the system path and reconfigured the lyx installation. But I still get the warnings.

Moreover the tools>tex information shows all the 3 files are present.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps you installed bundled lyx and have now two miktex installations.

Comment: Maybe   it remains to be done a Tools > Reconfigure ans restart LyX.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, yes I did install the bundle. I don't know how this is a problem, or how to resolve this. I have gone back to using TeXworks for the time being, so I'm trying to learn LateX syntax for that.